# Question about two limits at specific values (High School)

Tags: calculus, limits

A couple of things are tripping me up about some limit-related questions:

1.) If the $\lim_{x\to -2} \left(\frac{fx}{x^2}\right) = 1$, find $\lim_{x\to -2}f(x)$.

So I know that $\lim_{x\to a} \left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)$ = $\left(\frac{\lim_{x\to a} f(x)}{\lim_{x\to a} g(x)}\right)$; if that's the case, then it should follow that $$\lim_{x\to -2} f(x) = \lim_{x\to -2} x^2 = (-2)^2 = 4$$

and thus $\lim_{x\to -2} f(x) = 4$. It seems to me that this would satisfy the original proposition that  $\lim_{x\to -2} \left(\frac{fx}{x^2}\right) = 1$... is this right, though?

2.) Find $$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{6}}\sqrt{\csc^2x + 5\sqrt{3}\tan x)}$$

$\csc^2 x $ and $\tan x$ are both continuous at $\frac{\pi}{6}$, and the subsequent operations on their results ultimately yield a value greater than 0 for the argument of the square root, so a direct substitution for the value of x to find the limit 'should' work.

I feel like that's too easy, though... is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your answer is correct on both questions.

Comment: For #1 in particular, *assuming the limit exists*, yes, it is $4$.

Comment: @Clarinetist You do not need to assume that the limit exists. If you write it as $f(x)= x^2\frac{f(x)}{x^2}$ in a neighborhood of $x=-2$ and then take the limits, you see that it really does exist.

Comment: @air I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide some closure for this question (as not to fill up MSE with unanswered questions), you aren't missing anything. Both observations are correct.... not much else to say.
(MSE really need a way to accept comments as answers at some point... it would simplify this)